# How to interpolate data on unstructured grid?

Tags: differential-equations, interpolation

I have the Hamilton system in 3D case

```
    HamSysFull[Psi_, Theta_,  alpha_] := 
 NDSolve[{X'[t] == 
    Hp[X[t], Y[t],  Z[t], P[t], Q[t], Omega[t]], 
    Y'[t] == Hq[X[t], Y[t],  Z[t], P[t], Q[t], Omega[t]],  
    Z'[t] == 
    HOmega[X[t], Y[t],  Z[t], P[t], Q[t],  Omega[t]], 
    P'[t] == -Hx[X[t], Y[t],  Z[t], P[t], Q[t], Omega[t]], 
    Q'[t] == -Hy[X[t], Y[t],  Z[t], P[t], 
    Q[t],  Omega[t]], Omega'[t] == -Hz[X[t], Y[t], Z[t], P[t], Q[t],   Omega[t]], 
    X[0] == Xst[alpha, Psi, Theta],
    Y[0] == Yst[alpha, Psi, Theta],
    Z[0] == Zst[alpha, Psi, Theta],
    P[0] == Pst[Psi, Theta], Q[0] == Qst[Psi, Theta],
    Omega[0] == Omegast[Psi, Theta]},  {X, 
    Y, Z, P, Q, Omega}, {t, 0, NumT}, 
    StepMonitor :> { Sow[{{t, Psi, Theta}, X[t]}, x],  
     Sow[{{t, Psi, Theta}, Y[t]}, y],  
     Sow[{{t, Psi, Theta}, Z[t]}, z],  
     Sow[{{t, Psi, Theta}, P[t]}, p],  
     Sow[{{t, Psi, Theta}, Q[t]}, q],  
     Sow[{{t, Psi, Theta}, Omega[t]}, Omega]}]
```

After I solve if for different angles psi and theta

```
angleBound = Pi/4;
htheta = 2 angleBound/10;
hpsi = Pi/10;
fullSol = Table[Reap[HamSysFull[Psi, Theta, 0];], {Psi, 0, 
2 Pi, hpsi}, {Theta, -angleBound, angleBound, htheta}];
```

And for each solution I build the list for interpolation

```
 XTbl = Flatten[Table[fullSol[[i, j, 2, 1]], 
{i, 1, Length[fullSol]}, {j,1,Length[fullSol[[i]]]}], 2];
```

But the command

```
xInt = Interpolation[XTbl]
```

returns the error

```
 Interpolation::udeg: Interpolation on unstructured grids is currently only supported for InterpolationOrder->1 or InterpolationOrder->All. Order will be reduced to 1. >>
```

My question is how to interpolate such list of data. As I assumed it is because the unstructured grid by time. Making the structured grid is not a good option because it takes a lot of evalution.

Initial conditions for the system

```
Hdepth = 4000;
Epsilon = 0.00737;
A = 1500;
beta = 2;
z0 = 1300;
Zf[z_] := beta (z - z0)/z0;
c[z_] := A (1 + Epsilon (Zf[z] - 1 + Exp[-Zf[z]])); 



H[X_, Y_,  Z_, P_, Q_,  Omega_] :=  c[-Z] Sqrt[P^2 + Q^2 + Omega^2] 
Hp[X_, Y_,  Z_, P_, Q_,  Omega_] := D[H[X, Y, Z, P, Q, Omega], P];
Hq[X_, Y_,  Z_, P_, Q_,  Omega_] := D[H[X, Y, Z, P, Q, Omega], Q];
HOmega[X_, Y_,  Z_, P_, Q_, Omega_] := D[H[X, Y, Z, P, Q, Omega], Omega];
Hx[X_, Y_,  Z_, P_, Q_, Omega_] := D[H[X, Y, Z, P, Q, Omega], X];
Hy[X_, Y_,  Z_, P_, Q_, Omega_] := D[H[X, Y, Z, P, Q, Omega], Y];
Hz[X_, Y_,  Z_, P_, Q_, Omega_] := D[H[X, Y, Z, P, Q, Omega], Z];

Clear[x, z, p, Omega, Xpsi, Zpsi, Ppsi, Omegapsi, solution, t];

stDepth = -2000;  (* depth by z *)
stShiftx = 0;  (* shifting by x *)
stShifty = 0;  (* shifting by  *)
stPoint = {stShiftx, stShifty, stDepth}; (* starting conditions *)
alpha = 0; (* coordinate on manifold *)

Pst[Psi_, Theta_] := Cos[Psi] Cos[Theta]; 
Qst[Psi_, Theta_] := Sin[Psi] Cos[Theta];
Omegast[Psi_, Theta_] := Sin[Theta];
Xst[Alpha_ , Psi_, Theta_] := stPoint[[1]];
Yst[Alpha_ , Psi_, Theta_] := stPoint[[2]];
Zst[Alpha_ , Psi_, Theta_] := stPoint[[3]];

NumT = 10;
```

Comment: What happens if you set InterpolationOrder to 1: `xInt = Interpolation[XTbl, IterpolationOrder->1]`?

Comment: @Quantum_Oli It gives another series of errors about the grid: Interpolation::femimq: The element mesh has insufficient quality of -5.22882*10^-16. A quality estimate below 0. may be caused by a wrong ordering of element incidents or self-intersecting elements. >>8

Comment: @andre Don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @andre I've found it - while copying here made syntax error. But the question remains.

Comment: @andre I added initial conditions for the system at the end of the post.

Comment: I think what you need to do is, instead of using the `StepMonitor` data, utilize the `InterpolatingFunction` produced by `NDSolve` to extract data at regularly spaced points, then you will end up with a structured grid.

Comment: @george2079 This is a possible solution. But it takes a lot of computation. Therefore I wanted to optimize the computation time.

Answer (score 3):

this requires no more computation, remove the `StepMonitor` and move the `Sow` to a table evaluated after `NDSolve` has finished:

```
HamSysFull[Psi_, Theta_, alpha_] := 
 Module[{res}, 
  res = First@
    NDSolve[{X'[t] == Hp[X[t], Y[t], Z[t], P[t], Q[t], Omega[t]], 
      Y'[t] == Hq[X[t], Y[t], Z[t], P[t], Q[t], Omega[t]], 
      Z'[t] == HOmega[X[t], Y[t], Z[t], P[t], Q[t], Omega[t]], 
      P'[t] == -Hx[X[t], Y[t], Z[t], P[t], Q[t], Omega[t]], 
      Q'[t] == -Hy[X[t], Y[t], Z[t], P[t], Q[t], Omega[t]], 
      Omega'[t] == -Hz[X[t], Y[t], Z[t], P[t], Q[t], Omega[t]], 
      X[0] == Xst[alpha, Psi, Theta], Y[0] == Yst[alpha, Psi, Theta], 
      Z[0] == Zst[alpha, Psi, Theta], P[0] == Pst[Psi, Theta], 
      Q[0] == Qst[Psi, Theta], Omega[0] == Omegast[Psi, Theta]}, {X, 
      Y, Z, P, Q, Omega}, {t, 0, NumT}];
  Table[Sow[{{t, Psi, Theta}, (X[t] /. res)}, x], {t, 0, NumT, NumT/100}];
  Table[Sow[{{t, Psi, Theta}, (Y[t] /. res)}, y], {t, 0, NumT, NumT/100}]]
```

now with the rest of your code unchanged, `Interpolation[XTbl]` works fine.