# Make NDSolve return solution over only part of domain

Tags: differential-equations, performance-tuning, finite-element-method, interpolation

Consider the following pair of PDEs, for which I will solve in the mesh built below. The mesh needs to be much larger than the region of interest to mimic boundary conditions "at infinity".

However, as I would like to NIntegrate the resulting interpolating function as fast as possible, and noting that NIntegrate would [take longer to integrate over the same part of the domain if the interpolating function itself has a larger domain](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/164832/interpolation-function-and-numerical-integration), how could I make NDSolve return the solution only within a specified region of interest, hopefully within the same amount of time as the standard computation time?

Based on the reference [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/129686/how-to-interpolate-data-on-unstructured-grid), I tried using Reap and Sow to extract the values, but it seems to severely slow the NDSolve computation down (5 times slower) especially as I would like the data at all points of the mesh within the region of interest.

Understand if this is not possible! Thank you!

Code:
Mesh and Parameters (area of interest is x < Xint)

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
(*Define Some Helper Functions For Structured Meshes*)

pointsToMesh[data_] := 
  MeshRegion[Transpose[{data}], 
   Line@Table[{i, i + 1}, {i, Length[data] - 1}]];
unitMeshGrowth[n_, r_] := 
 Table[(r^(j/(-1 + n)) - 1.)/(r - 1.), {j, 0, n - 1}]
meshGrowth[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := (xf - x0) unitMeshGrowth[n, r] + x0
firstElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@First@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
lastElmHeight[x0_, xf_, n_, r_] := 
 Abs@Last@Differences@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, r]
findGrowthRate[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 Quiet@Abs@
   FindRoot[
     firstElmHeight[x0, xf, n, r] - fElm, {r, 0.00000001, 
      100000000/fElm}, Method -> "Brent"][[1, 2]]
meshGrowthByElm[x0_, xf_, n_, fElm_] := 
 N@Sort@Chop@meshGrowth[x0, xf, n, findGrowthRate[x0, xf, n, fElm]]
meshGrowthByElm0[len_, n_, fElm_] := meshGrowthByElm[0, len, n, fElm]
flipSegment[l_] := (#1 - #2) & @@ {First[#], #} &@Reverse[l];
leftSegmentGrowth[len_, n_, fElm_] := meshGrowthByElm0[len, n, fElm]
rightSegmentGrowth[len_, n_, fElm_] := 
 Module[{seg}, seg = leftSegmentGrowth[len, n, fElm];
  flipSegment[seg]]
reflectRight[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{1}, {Last@pts}]}, 
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
reflectLeft[pts_] := 
 With[{rt = ReflectionTransform[{-1}, {First@pts}]}, 
  Union[pts, Flatten[rt /@ Partition[pts, 1]]]]
extendMesh[mesh_, newmesh_] := Union[mesh, Max@mesh + newmesh]

Xint = 0.015; (*area of interest*)

a = 60.;

(*Simulation properties*)
rl = 0;
rb = 0.3;

h1 = Xint; h2 = rb - Xint;
v = 1.5;(*Vertical*)d = 3.;(*Depth*)
(*Number of elements per segment*)
nh1 = 20; nh2 = 8; nv = 8; nd = 12;
(*Association for Clearer Region Assignment*)
reg = <|"left" -> 1, "right" -> 2|>;
(*Horizontal segments*)
(*left segment*)
sh1 = Subdivide[h1, nh1];
(*Make right segment uniform mesh size*)
sh2 = flipSegment@meshGrowthByElm0[h2, nh2, h2/5];
(*Glue segments together*)
segh = extendMesh[sh1, sh2];
(*View individual horizontal segments*)
Print["Horizontal segments"]
Print["Inside sphere, cell spacing is: ", h1/nh1]
pointsToMesh /@ {sh1, sh2}
(*View combined segments*)
Print["Combined horizontal segments"]
rh = pointsToMesh@segh
(*Vertical Segment*)
Print["Vertical segment"]
rv = pointsToMesh@Subdivide[v, nv] (*uniform mesh size*)
(*View Region Product of horiz and vert segs*)
Print["2D Region via RegionProduct"]
RegionProduct[rh, rv]
(*Depth Segment*)
Print["Depth segment"]
rd = pointsToMesh@Subdivide[d, nd]
(*Create a tensor product grid from h,v,and d segments*)
rp = RegionProduct[rh, rv, rd];
(*View mesh*)
(*Print["Full Extruded 3D Region via RegionProduct"]
HighlightMesh[rp,Style[1,Orange]]*)
(*Extract Coords from RegionProduct*)
crd = MeshCoordinates[rp];
(*grab hexa element incidents RegionProduct mesh*)
inc = Delete[0] /@ MeshCells[rp, 3];
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> crd, "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[inc]}];
(*Extract bmesh*)
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[mesh];
(*Iron RegionMember Function*)
\[CapitalOmega]3Diron = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {h1, v, d}];
rmf = RegionMember[\[CapitalOmega]3Diron];
regmarkerfn = If[rmf[#], reg["left"], reg["right"]] &;
(*Get mean coordinate of each hexa for region marker assignment*)
mean = Mean /@ GetElementCoordinates[mesh["Coordinates"], #] & /@ElementIncidents[mesh["MeshElements"]] // First;
regmarkers = regmarkerfn /@ mean;
(*Create and view element mesh*)
Print["Converted Hexa Element Mesh"]
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> mesh["Coordinates"], 
   "MeshElements" -> {HexahedronElement[inc, regmarkers]}];
meshupdated = MeshOrderAlteration[mesh /. elem : {__HexahedronElement} :> {HexahedronElement @@ Join @@@ Transpose[elem /. HexahedronElement -> List]}, 2]
```

NDSolve

```
With[{ny = ny[x, y, z], nz = nz[x, y, z]},
 eq1 = Expand[Laplacian[ny, {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"]] == 
   ny - a*(D[ny, z] - D[nz, z] - (2 + nz));
 eq2 = Expand[Laplacian[(2 + nz), {x, y, z}, "Cartesian"]] == 
   2 + nz - a*(D[ny, y] + D[nz, y] + ny);
 bc1y = ny == 0. /. x -> rb;
 bc1z = nz == 0. /. x -> rb;
 ]
{nysol, nzsol} = NDSolveValue[{eq1, eq2, bc1y, bc1z}, {ny, nz}, {x, y, z} \[Element]meshupdated]
```

Comment: A comment for future posts: You posted a lot of code. It is usually better if you can find a few lines of code (a minimal example) that illustrate and isolate the problem. This increases the chances of getting useful answers, and it also increases the chances that your question is useful to future visitors.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback! I'm sorry I wasn't sure what to remove because the bulk of the code before NDSolve was necessary to construct the mesh.

Comment: Parameter `c` is not defined.

Comment: I apologise c is 2, have updated the code.